# implementing search box event handler in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a similar key-event handler that is used in Google search or Bing search. So basically after you write your input in the input search box, whenever you press the keyboard arrow down or up, it would highlight one of the result. So say you google stackoverflow on google.

[image]

as you can see, there are 4 similar recommended results. From here, if I click the arrow down button from the keyboard, it will highlight the background of "stack overflow" and change the input to "stack overflow" from just "stackoverflow". This is what I wrote so far

```
$("#inputSelector).keydown(function(e){
var currentInput = $(this).val();
switch(e.which){
case 38:
    break;
case 40:
    break;
default:
    break;
}
}
```

Case 38 is for up-keyboard and 40 is for the down-keyboard. I'm not sure how to keep track of the current position of the result. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Note you have a typo, forgot to close the quote when you gave the code: `$("#inputSelector")`.

Comment: Is there a reason for creating this from scratch? search for jquery ui autocomplete

Comment: @Dekel wow i was not aware of that, thank you!